# Is there a database of all known star names/identifiers?

Tags: star, data-analysis, naming, raw-data

I am looking for a list of all known identifiers used for stars. I'm not sure on the terminology. While I do want the "[proper names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proper_names_of_stars)", I also want whatever identifier is used for each star detected, even those without proper names. I am assuming there are far more of the latter.

If possible I would also like to have the coordinates and brightness (and any other interesting info) for each of these star. But just the list of identifiers would be great.

Does such data exist somewhere? Ideally I can just download a simple file (like a csv) and I can write my own software to process it without fiddling with some other software. However, it may be too large for that.

I'm not sure what to expect... 1 million entries?

Comment: You might want to clarify what you are using the information for or if a reasonable brightness limit can be set. Do you want the 10000 or so stars that are visible with the unaided eye, or the billion of stars that are too faint to be visible with the unaided eye? Then, there are often multiple designations for the same star (proper name, Flamsteed number, Bayer designation, SAO number, HD number, etc.) How much information do you want?

Comment: @JohnHoltz I would want every designation available for each object if possible, but if not, the one that includes the most stars. Various brightness limits could work for my purposes (even just the top 10k that you mentioned), but I figured I would just get it all now and then filter later.

Comment: Gaia catalog has a lot (1,142,679,769) of stars. Here you have catalog: https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/. More about Gaia mission: https://zah.uni-heidelberg.de/institutes/ari/gaia/.

Comment: @User123 Thanks, that looks like a good one.

Comment: @User123 FYI. I attempted to [search](https://gea.esac.esa.int/archive/) "T Tau" as in the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nswGqcyGv8s) and it didn't work. I got "T Tau Not resolved".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest service to what you are describing is the [SIMBAD Astronomical Database](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/) from the Université de Strasbourg/CNRS. At the time I write this post, it contains 10.8M objects and 35.5M identifiers. It does not have a single CSV you can download with this information (to the best of my knowledge, and I've asked), but there is an API and [TAP service](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-tap#) available for programmatic access.